# Crystal reports shows info on preview but not when generating the report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

[image: Crystal Reports Preview]

[image]

I'm building a report for a client, and Crystal reports shows the correct values in preview, but when I try to pull the report from our application, its just blank space... Could someone shed some light on why this might be happenning?

I'm definitely not a Crystal Reports expert but this is the reporting tool our company uses, so I need to make it work somehow.

If you need any more info on the report, please let me know and i'll gather as much info as possible.

Comment: Have you installed the Crystal Report Runtime Engine on the computer where the app is installed?

Comment: Yes, of course. I must have Crystal Report RunTime installed to even open the report, otherwise it would just thrown an error.